# Probability and the meaning of the sentence "for every n turns...."

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I understand that this is a relatively simple problem but the way my friend put it, sort of got me confused.

So I have 8 balls-5 green and 3 red.

> What is the probability of picking a green ball?

I told him that it was 5/8.

He now asks me to say it as a sentence, and I told him

> for every 8 turns that I get, there's a probability that I may end up with a green ball 5 out of those 8 times.

Is my reply correct? I sort of feel that there's something that I'm missing here.

Moreover, how does the above sentence change when I reduce the number of turns to 7,6,....1 while keeping the number of balls the same? I e. How does the probability change when the number of turns alone changes, keeping the sample space the same? Eg: Same 8 balls, but I get to choose only 6 times. How does the probability change?

I feel that this question^ arises from the reply I gave earlier, hence I think there's something missing here. Could someone please help?

Comment: But what is wrong with or missing in a sentence like: "If I pick randomly one ball then the probability that this ball is green will be $\frac58$"? If I had to answer then I would not involve "turns" whatsoever. At most I should add something like: "if I do this lots of times then the percentage of times resulting in a green ball will get closer and closer to $\frac58\times100$ percent." By one turn each of the green balls has a chance of $\frac18$ to be picked. We have $5$ such balls  so the probabilty on  a green ball adds up to $\frac58$.

Comment: No I'm looking into the meaning of the sentence "the probability that this ball is green" or rather specifically, the meaning of the word *probability* itself.

Comment: Then it looks to me as a question concerning language/semantics/philosophy and not a question concerning mathematics. In mathematics we build models of reality and practicize probability measures (I can tell you about them) in order to "catch" the capricuous thing that we label as "probability" (I know nothing more than you about this) in the real world.